# Обновление бд с помощью crontab

Tags: cron, база-данных, php

Помогите сделать скрипт и наладить работу с кроном, чтобы:

1. Каждые 6 часов скачивался

   ```
   http://download.forum3.ru/download/forum_csv.zip
   ```
2. Распаковывался (`forum.csv`);
3. Обновлял таблицу `table` в базе данных.

Answer (score 3):

Набросок скрипта-костыля. Криво, наколенно, но может работать, если в CSV не влепят ничего намеренно злого:

```
#!/bin/sh

curl http://download.forum3.ru/download/forum_csv.zip \
    | funzip \
    | perl -e 'while(<>) {
          chomp;
          my @r = map { s/\x27/\\\x27/; "\x27$_\x27" } split /;/;
          print "INSERT INTO table VALUES (".join(", ", @r).");\n";}' \
    | mysqlimport ...
```

Это скрипт «шелла», конкретно — Bourne shell (/bin/sh). По сути, обычный текстовый файл. Первой строкой идет hashbang («`#!`») с указанием интерпретатора, и дальше текст скрипта. Если поставить `chmod +x` (скажем, `0770` aka `rwxrwx---`), то файл будет «выполнимым», система по hashbang'у запустит интерпретатор и т.д.. А, да, и работает это все только на *unix-системах. На Windows® — только если под Cygwin.

В crontab'е: `0 */6 * * * /путь/к/скрипту`. Возможно еще добавить после последней «`*`» еще поле — имя пользователя, если crontab системный.

Формат описан в `crontab(5)`.

- Минуты (0-59)
- Часы (0-23)
- День месяца (1-31)
- Месяц (1-12)
- День недели (0-7; 0 = 7 = воскресенье)

Можно использовать «`*`» (любое значение), диапазоны (`1-10`), списки (`1,2,4-6,12`) или задавать шаг (`*/6`).

**Update:**

Как и обещал, вариант на PHP. Не тестировал, но, если нигде не опечатался — должно работать.

```
<?php
    $filename = "forum_csv.zip";

    // Скачиваем файл используя cURL: http://ru2.php.net/manual/ru/book.curl.php
    $fp = fopen($filename, "w+");
    $ch = curl_init("http://download.forum3.ru/download/forum_csv.zip");
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 50);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FILE, $fp);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, true);
    curl_exec($ch);
    curl_close($ch);
    fclose($fp);

    // Открываем файл как ZIP-архив.
    // Используем для этого функции для работы
    //   с ZIP-архивами: http://ru2.php.net/manual/ru/book.zip.php
    $zip = zip_open($filename);
    if ($zip) {
        // Читаем записи в ZIP-архиве, пока не найдем с именем "forum.csv"
        // (или не прочитаем все что было)
        do {
            $entry = zip_read($zip);
        } while ($entry && zip_entry_name($entry) != "forum.csv");

        if ($entry) {
            // Если forum.csv нашли, то прочитаем его. Весь в память.
            // Это не эффективно (файл может быть большой), но проще.
            zip_entry_open($zip, $entry, "r");
            $csv = zip_entry_read($entry, zip_entry_filesize($entry));

            // Подключимся к MySQL. Параметры впишете, если надо.
            // См. http://ru2.php.net/manual/ru/function.mysql-connect.php
            mysql_connect();

            // Разобъем на строки по "\n".
            foreach(explode("\n", $csv) as $line) {
                // Используем функцию для чтения CSV:
                // http://ru2.php.net/manual/ru/function.str-getcsv.php
                // И за'escape'им каждый элемент полученного массива.
                $items = array_map("mysql_real_escape_string", str_getcsv($line, ";"));
                // Собственно, делаем запрос. Какой-то.
                // Тут явно надо править под конкретную структуру БД.
                // Сначала проверяйте, заменив "mysql_query" на "echo".
                mysql_query("INSERT INTO table VALUES ('" .
                            implode("','", $items) . "');");
            }

            zip_entry_close($entry);
        }
        zip_close($zip);
    }
?>
```

В crontab прописывать строчку в духе:

```
 0 */6 * * * /usr/bin/php /home/username/import-csv.php
```

Как-то так.

**Update2:**

Как выяснилось, [похапэ не может в чтение ZIP-архива через `http://`](http://www.mail-archive.com/php-bugs@lists.php.net/msg44099.html). Поправил скрипт на работу со временным файлом.

Comment: Прошу прощения за глупый вопрос, куда это всё и как ?

Comment: Скрипт - в файл (не забыв `chmod +x`, чтобы тот был исполнимым), строчку с параметрами (где его путь) — в `/etc/crontab` или локальный crontab пользователя (редактируется по `crontab -e`).

Comment: файл какого характера? html? txt ?  я просто кроме как с php ни на чём не работал, у меня всё только начинается

Comment: Ну, в данном случае — шелловый скрипт для sh (Bourne shell). А, ладно, погодите немного, попробую набросать на PHP.